# Is there a way to kill a running workqueue immediately without waiting for it to finish in linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

Without changing existing workqueue function, is there anyway to kill the running workqueue immediately from the code(not `cancel_work_sync()` but more like `kill -9`)?

Comment: Did you see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973583/how-to-immediately-cancel-a-work-item-of-a-workqueue-in-a-linux-kernel-module)?

Comment: Yes I have but it's not quite what I am looking for. My work function calls another library function which I don't have source access, somehow it got stuck inside the library function. So I am wondering if there is a way to kill the workqueue like 'ps -9'